# How to send data on a curl redirect?

Tags: python, web-services, curl, flask, https

I have an API which is currently on HTTP, I moved the API using SSLify library in python flask. 
Now when I send data using curl request

```
curl -v -k  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
  --data '{"title":"foobar","body": "This body"}' \
  -L http://X.Y.Z.W.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/test
```

It returns an empty string to me by using request.data
If I make the request to begin with https it returns correct value. If there is a redirect how can I send data ?

Comment: google follow redirects in curl

Answer (score 5):

SSLify issues a 301 or 302 redirect status code depending on your configuration. So you need to pass `--post301` or `--post302` to curl.

The reason for this can be found in the curl man page:

> When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for
>   example POST or PUT), it will do the following request  with  a   GET 
>   if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was
>   any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request   using
>   the same unmodified method.
>
> You can tell curl to not change the non-GET request method to GET
>   after a 30x response by using  the  dedicated  options  for  that: --post301, --post302 and -post303.

Comment: oh bud that was so useful, it looks like it works. Thank you both of you.